# What's the proper position of »hat« in this sentence from »Der Spiegel«?

Tags: sentence-structure

The below sentence appears in the article “[Niederlandes Wahlgewinner Rutte. Sieg der Vernunft.](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/niederlande-wahl-der-erdogan-faktor-bei-ruttes-sieg-a-1138969.html)” from *Der Spiegel*:

> Trotzdem **hat** [Marine] Le Pen **hat** immer noch reelle Chancen,
>   französische Präsidentin zu werden.

It seems that the author of the above sentence was hesitating where to place the verb *hat* and ultimately forgot to remove the redundant one. So, which *hat* is redundant: first or second? Or is the sentence actually correctly written?

Comment: Der Spiegel has already corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hat** is the finite verb in your example sentence. Thus, it can appear at only three possible positions: first, second or last. Last position would imply a subordinate clause which in turn would require a corresponding conjunction which is not present. (And there is no *hat* suggested at the end of the sentence.) And first-position finite verbs are only possible if they are imperatives, questions (not the case) or unmarked conditional clauses (also not). This means that *hat* must be in second position.

The second *hat* is therefore only possible if *trotzdem* were a conjunction that occupies zeroth position. But that cannot be the case here because it is not connecting two main clauses: it is merely the first word of a main clause.

Because *trotzdem* is not a conjunction it occupies the first position, *hat* must follow immediately (we are obviously in a main clause) and placing it after the subject is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

In this case **»Trotzdem«** starts a main clause, so

> Trotzdem **hat** [Marine] Le Pen immer noch reelle Chancen,
>   französische Präsidentin zu werden.

is correct. Kill the second **»hat«**, a double **»hat«** is no option.

Answer (score 1):

No, this sentence is not correct. The correct position of "hat" is the first:

> Trotzdem **hat** [Marine] Le Pen immer noch reelle Chancen, französische Präsidentin zu werden.